# How do I enable a utility like screentogif or key'n'stroke to be able to record mouse position when inside vmware or "protected" applications?

Tags: windows-10, mouse, vmware, events

I am making very complicated tutorials and I absolutely need these two features.  I need to be able to display the distinction between right and left clicks, for example.  It takes hours to make a tutorial, but much longer without being able to use mouse clicks to trigger screen shots, or use my key'n'stroke program to display mouse click options.

Tried disabling all security features in Vmware, side channel mitigations, usb settings, etc.  can't get it to work.

It has something to do with security features, am I right?  or is it something else?

Comment: Install Snagit or Like inside the VMware Guest

Comment: My only issue with installing them inside the VM guest, is that the guest must be booted, fully installed, etc. also some VM's I'm working with can not run any such program.

Comment: Ask who ever is restricting the machines to install for you.